# How to control volume on Apple TV using iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, appletv, hdmi

I have an Apple TV 4K (tvOS 14.2), connected the Apple TV 4K to a 1-year old Samsung 4K TV through HDMI, and use an iPhone 11 (Apple TV Remote) to control it.

The issue is that I cannot adjust the volume on the Apple TV 4K by decreasing/increasing the volume on my iPhone (iPhone side-volume buttons or Apple TV Remote)

I contacted Apple support and they couldn't really provide any helpful feedback.

**Why can't I control the volume on the Apple TV 4K using my iPhone 11, when I can control the volume on a Chromecast Ultra connected through the same HDMI port?**

Comment: On the ATV, go to `Settings -> Remotes and Devices > Volume Control`.  Is it set to "Auto"?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also, the other options don’t seem to work when set explicitly. Does it work for you?

Comment: I have an old TV and use a receiver for my audio, neither of which are [supported for using the iPhone to control volume](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205225).

Comment: I honestly don't think there's a way to control volume with the phone-based remote.  Not only have I not heard of this before (although that's not a guarantee of it not being possible, of course), but I can't see how this could possibly work.  The Siri/touchpad remote has both RF and IR transmitters, and the ATV itself (ATV4 and higher) has RF and IR receivers.  To control volume, you point your original remote at the ATV, which receives the IR codes, and sends them back to the remote (I assume), and it's the ATV remote which sends the IR codes to control your volume.  iPhones can't do that.

Comment: @jimtut - can you tell me how Chromecast is able to control volume then?

Comment: Just a guess, never used one, but it must be sending a control signal over HDMI, according to this guy's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeBokBu7Lck.  If ATV can do this too, I'd love to know, but I've never seen it on any of my ATV4, just the IR control, connected to a LOT of different amps and TV's.